# What is the correct verb here? Is or are?

Tags: grammar, verbs, nouns, lists

Example: 
“In the performance category is the/are the/there are:

1) Al-Taghrooda, a traditional Bedouin chanted poetry

2) Al-Ayyala, a traditional performing art

3) Al-Azi, a traditional recital

Comment: Well. How many thing is there in the category.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply! There are 8 things. Proper nouns at the beginning of each point

Comment: “There are 8 entrants in the performance category: list.”  The list items function as addenda to the sentence which should otherwise be whole and complete without the list present. The list should not be the object of the verb or serve any other essential grammar function in the sentence that introduces it. C.f. Elements of Style, Strunk and White, #7

Answer (score -1):

> “In the performance category, is the: 1., 2., 3.,
>
> “In the performance category, are the: 1., 2., 3.,

These are incorrect/substandard as “the“ does not normally precede a numbered list.

“*In the performance category, there **is**: 1., 2., 3.,*” This is correct because you have a list:  “1., and 2., and 3., and etc.. i.e. [there is] this, and [there is] this, and [there is] this, and [there is] etc.

Example:

"In the box, there is one, a button, two, a candle, three a bus ticket."

**There** is an adverb that causes a subject-verb inversion.

Comment: A list should be introduced by an *independent* clause followed by a colon. The list is not to be seen as a simple continuation of the sentence. “In the performance category there are 8 entrants: ...” “The performance category contains the following items: ...” Strunk and White, Elements of Style item #7, page 19.

Comment: View it an an enumeration of individual items... See the example.

Comment: I agree your example is grammatical.I do not agree that the enumerated form is suited to the case given.A category seldom has only a single element or none. Which I think is important possibility for the enumerated singular. In a list of 8 elements, each of which is a multi-word title beginning each with an enumeration within a sentence framework would, one, make it difficult for the reader to follow, two, fail at keeping sentence length down, three, confuse rather than organize the listed information, four, cause the reader to forget the subject and verb of the sentence they are still reading

Comment: Sorry, character limit caused me to eliminate some words which I had thought were superfluous, but that I now see had made the tone of my comment far more convivial than it now reads. My comment now sounds shrill and harsh and altogether lacking in mirth and esprit de corp which I had intended for it.